# How to remove all login errors on wp-login.php - lostpassword

Tags: wordpress, passwords

Does anyone know how to entirely get rid of login errors?

Not just by replacing/removing the text with add_filter( 'login_errors'), but completely preventing wordpress sending ''

I would like to prevent the lostpassword form revealing if the username is correct or not. I already redirected, its just the error that is indicating a wrong user name...

Thanks!

[Text is removed, but the error message is still present in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwjrE.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the html for error message using css:

```
<?php function hide_error() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
       .login #login_error{
           display: none;
       }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'hide_error' ); ?>
```